# What's lacking about the Kerch Strait land bridge, between Crimea and Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, transportation, infrastructure, crimea

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt2L14RcWP0), retired US Army General and former CIA Director David Petraeus tells CNN's Jake Tapper how the Ukrainian people have aided their army in killing multiple Russian generals. CNN has not been able to confirm the killings.

At [3 minutes 59 seconds](https://youtu.be/dt2L14RcWP0?t=239), David Petraeus and Jake Tapper discussed military logistics around Crimea:

> Petraeus: It's also that you have a land line of communication between essentially Russia and Crimea that doesn't require the bridge here.
>
> Tapper: Let's go back to the corridor here.  This is what they had previously, all they had was this teeny little bridge which you can't really get everything you need ...
>
> Petraeus: That's right.
>
> Tapper: ... if you're in the Russian military, across this bridge.  It's just not big enough.
>
> Petraeus: That's right, that's right.

Is Petraeus referring to [Kerch Strait Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Bridge), a pair of Russian-constructed parallel bridges, spanning the Strait of Kerch between the Taman Peninsula in Russia and the Kerch Peninsula of Crimea?

Why isn't it big enough? What does Russia need to accomplish that can't be accomplished with this 'teeny' bridge?

Comment: I am not sure how this is related to politics. I guess it might be connected to Russia's military actions in Southern Ukraine, but it should be explicitly mentioned in the post.

Comment: My guess would be that you can't get a tank accross because they would be too heavy. Tanks are much heavier than the trucks that regularly go over roads/ bridges (especially per area) and bridges in general or not build to support the extra weight of tanks.

Comment: @quarague, we're talking about a fairly substantial bridge. But in wartime, a single bridge is much too vulnerable.

Comment: @o.m. Some quick googling gives a weight of around 80 tons for a big modern tank and about 20 tons for a big truck. One certainly can build bridges that can carry tanks but it costs extra and I have no idea whether it was done in this case.

Comment: @Alexei: state-paid infrastructure is generally on-topic, even if not related to war objectives.

Comment: The argument is pretty weird. given that it's also a railway bridge. I'm pretty sure tanks can be carried across it. I could see it being much more vulnerable to attack, but that would take precision missiles which Ukraine rather lacks. Maybe he was talking about total capacity and congestion, but that's not terribly explicit.

Comment: There are some images [here](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-video-shows-tanks-military-equipment-leaving-crimea-2022-02-16/) of a military train crossing the bridge, although there are only IFVs seen in the images, so maybe heavier tank are more of a problem, but I'm still skeptical. A diesel locomotive easily weighs 100-200 tons, depending on the model. Actually video here shows MBTs too https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-europe-60400649

Comment: By the way, it wasn't Petraeus whos said that. It was Jake Tapper, but Petraeus agreed.

Comment: I think this question would better fit on an engineering stack. I mean, reading the Wikipedia page, the bridge placement is problematic unstable soil in a tectonic region), and was built prioritizing the idea of bringing it into operation quickly, not structural soundness. But that's not something we're qualified to analyze. The only political issue is that a single bridge — particularly one as long as this — is extremely vulnerable. one well-aimed missile or bomb could cut communication between Russia and Crimea, as well as dumping hundreds tons of Russian equipment into the sea.

Comment: Looking a bit more at this, Wesley Clark has basically retired 20 years ago, and has spent a lot of time since then trying to make into politics. While he seems to be the darling of CNN on military commentaries, he's probably not quite in the loop especially on details like that. The  Kerch railway bridge was only opened for freight traffic in 2020, as far as I can tell.

Comment: There is a civil engineering stack exchange, which might have expertise on technical issues of a bridge. As I understand it here, it might be a question of throughput and length of supply lines.

Comment: @quarague Russian tanks weigh 46-48 mt (a very narrow range all of them fit into). Trucks are generally limited to 80,000 lbs, or 36 mt. It's not a big difference, well within the safety headroom, so Russian tanks would have no problem crossing any truck-capable bridge. It probably has more to do with the logistics vehicles.

Comment: @Fizz thanks for correcting me. just edit my post. why did you bring up Wesley Clark? He was not in the interview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bridge is easily sufficient for combat vehicles themselves.

Russian tanks weigh 46-48 mt (a very narrow range all of them fit into). Trucks are generally limited to 80,000 lbs, or 36 mt. It's not a big difference, well within the safety headroom, so Russian tanks would have no problem crossing any truck-capable bridge.

The rail line is also sufficient for war logistics.
A high-volume train line can carry up to 7 trains per hour at ~50 cars per train. At 60,000L per car, that's up to 500 million liters of fuel per day. Wartime caution and difficulties will reduce this.

A T-90 carries 1600 liters of fuel, about enough for a day of active operations. 1,000 tanks will thus consume about 1.6 million liters a day. Add another 25,000 lighter vehicles at half the consumption of a MBT each, and you can estimate ~20 million liters daily. That's 4% of the rail line's maximum peacetime capacity.

But there is of course the issue of the bridge's vulnerability. Since Russia considers Crimea its home soil, the bridge is protected by its nuclear deterrent. That could be tested, but the probability of a response is high, which would either end the war or start a new one. Still, in a full-scale war, a single bridge cannot be relied upon.

What the bridge is not sufficient for is distributing this fuel across the country. Once the train arrives to a station, it has to be unloaded and the fuel transloaded to trucks to carry it further. And this isn't done at a rate of 20 million liters per hour - this kind of transloading infrastructure just doesn't exist, anywhere in the world.

A land bridge can be traversed by ground vehicles directly. It can be used to lay temporary pipelines and railways. It also offers opportunity to use or install new infrastructure for fuel transloading.

Comment: Good answer overall, the bridge seems functional enough for now.  However, tank tracks [wear out quickly and chew up asphalt](https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/weapons/a32936404/russian-tank-street-destruction/).  Those tanks would be crossing the bridge on railroad cars or specialized tank moving trucks, not on their own.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of commentary has centered around the over-water bridge to Crimea. This is a "Red Herring" so to speak. Russia needs 'open year round' warm water ports for commercial shipping expansion (oil/gas transport not dependent on pipelines thru hostile/NATO territory) and to base naval operations. There was longstanding agreement between Russia and Ukraine to share naval base at Sevastopol but that wasn't good enough for Russia. Also, the Donbas region has long been place of plentiful resources (coal & iron, etc) and its associated manufacturing strengths.

ALSO... a couple well placed cruise missiles make the Kerch Straight bridge just another pile of useless rubble.